# Black text on toolbar item in Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have a toolbar with some items, and on andorid 7.1 my text is white, but on android 5.1 text is black. In appTheme i've setted a white color. How to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="clear"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

My xml file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:visibility="@{viewModel.isLoaded}">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/catalog_filter_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back_icon"
            app:title="Blue"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create resource type style for versions V21 and minors 
add in your file style.xml

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
```